# merge multiple dataframes with different columns names and different rows number

Tags: python, pandas

I want to merge many dataframes with 2 columns each: one common column `teams`, rows numbers in each dataframe is different, and teams can be present in different number of dataframe or all of them.

```
#df1
team_col    pattern_A
team_1      1
team_3      1
team_4      1
```

```
#df2
teams_col   pattern_B
team_1      1
team_2      1
```

```
#df3
team_col    pattern_C
team_2      1
team_4      1
team_5      1
```

```
#df4
team_col    pattern_D
team_1      1
team_3      1
team_5      1
```

I want a single dataframe with the column teams and all other columns. I want to associate each team with his patterns. Like below

```
team_col    pattern_A   pattern_B   pattern_C   pattern_D
team_1      1           1           0           1
team_2      0           1           1           0
team_3      1           0           0           1
team_4      1           0           1           0
team_5      0           0           1           1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
dfs = [df2,df3,df5]
df1 = df1.set_index('team_col')
for df in dfs:
   df1 = df1.add(df.set_index('team_col'),fill_values=0)
>>>df1.reset_index(drop=True)

team_col    pattern_A   pattern_B   pattern_C   pattern_D
team_1      1           1           0           1
team_2      0           1           1           0
team_3      1           0           0           1
team_4      1           0           1           0
team_5      0           0           1           1
```

Comment: return error: "TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "float") to str"

Comment: This probebly has to do with your dataframe dtypes.. can you tey to print each df as so `df.dtypes` ?

Comment: all dataframes has the "teams" column as object, and the second columns as int64

Comment: Im not in front of computer i will check in the morning, (its evening here) sorry for that one

Comment: Edited accordingly.. try now... forgot to reset index inplace